# php - How to create a random bit stream

Tags: php, arrays, random

How can I generate following random array:

```
array(1, 0 , 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

with `length = n`?

Of course, always the `for` solution is out there. But is there any **One-line** simple solution on this, like any combination of `array_fill` and `mt_rand(0, 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) (or `array_fill` if you need) to generate random values.

```
$length = 10;
$randBits = array_map(
    function () {
        return mt_rand(0, 1);
    },
    range(0, $length - 1)
);
```

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c46050ecd1a24ba00df66fcf16c17c6bec0defb3)

Comment: Thanks for ur nice answer. How does it apply to `array_fill` as you mentioned?

Comment: @Trix In this case `array_fill` mostly makes no difference (some performance changes will apply) because you will overwrite it's values with random generated.

Answer (score 0):

Use range with mt_rand

```
      $random_bit_stream = array_map(function() {
            return mt_rand(0,1);
        }, range(1,6));

or

 $random_bit_stream = array_map(function() {
            return rand(0,1);
        }, range(1,6));

        print_r($random_bit_stream);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 )
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
function randome_array($n)
{
    $array=array();
    $x = 1;
    while($x <= $n) {
    $temp = mt_rand(0,1);
        array_push($array,$temp);
        $x++;
    }
    return $array;
}
print_r(randome_array(5));
```

https://3v4l.org/ZSrMX

i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Well, as you mentioned, you could one-line the for solution.

`for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) $arr[$i] = rand(0, 1);`

aside that, since you mentioned `array_fill`, you could simply use it with the random function as well

`$arr = array_fill (0, count($arr), rand(0, 1));`

Comment: `array_fill (0, count($arr), rand(0, 1));` will only make first value random and than repeat it in all values.

Comment: @Justinas you're right, that was a stupid suggestion. Inline for loop will probably be the fastest solution either way, even though it does not completely match as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can try with range()

range — Create an array containing a range of elements

for more info check http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: I do not want more info, I want an answer

Comment: How can you gain the result with simply using `range`? please explain. Thanks

Comment: Do it yourself. You should have asked this question before asking direct answer..! Cant spoon feed you again...

Comment: No I didn't. But it has been deleted and I don't know why! Would you please explain how could `range` be used to produce a bitstream?